# INSERT values into multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, c#-4.0, oracle11g

I have tables named, `TBL_LOGIN, TBL_USER, TBL_PERMISSION, TBL_SECTION`. `TBL_LOGIN's` primary key is `user_name` and at other tables user_name is `foreign key`. I want to `insert that username with only one sql command`. How can i do that?

Thanks for support :)

Comment: How do you communicate with your db? What have you tried? Show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multi-table insert feature of oracle (from oracle 9i on)

```
CREATE TABLE TX1 ( X INT PRIMARY KEY, Y INT );
CREATE TABLE TX2 ( X INT PRIMARY KEY, Y DATE );

INSERT ALL 
INTO TX1 VALUES (PKNUM,COL1)
INTO TX2 VALUES (PKNUM,COL2)
SELECT 1 pknum
, 8 COL1
, sysdate COL2
from dual;
```